# use of collections to group nested form records - accessing proper index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

Rails [form helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) can call upon a a collection to be used.

Class Event `has_many :equipments, has_many :equipment_maintenanceitems`
Class Equipment `has_many :maintenanceitems` and, as events are created they inherit attributes of maintenanceitems (but not a relationship, i.e. they don't get updated)

However, when I employ the collection as follows

```
@event.equipments.each do |eq|
  eq.title
  @maintenance_for_eqs = @maintenanceitems.select{ |i| i.equipment_id == eq.id }
    @maintenance_for_eqs do |eq_maintenance|
    eq_maintenance.name
    f.fields_for :equipment_maintenanceitems, eq_maintenance do |equipment_maintenanceitem|
      equipment_maintenanceitem.object.id
      equipment_maintenanceitem.check_box :executed
```

While the object call is returning the proper id, the check_box is being identified with the array of counters starting at '0', as if it were a new build. `<input name="event[equipment_maintenanceitems_attributes][0][executed]" type="hidden" value="0" />`  while equipment_maintenanceitem.object.id returns "2".

As per documentation `Note that #fields_for will automatically generate a hidden field to store the ID of the record.` this is clearly not happening.

How can the check_box reference the attributes of the proper object?

Comment: Equipment is a mass noun. So its equipment in plural - not equipments. 

http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70828/what-is-the-plural-of-equipment

Comment: Fine.  But that is not at the root of the problem. I actually put that term in so as not to confuse readers with a foreign language, but get the gist...  Rails' pluralization is not always the most convenient thing.  The issue is that an improper index is being accessed by fields_for

Comment: I still think this is very confusing - I think for this to be understandable you should create a [proper verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And state what the desired outcome is in form of a params hash.  Also if the names are just figured a least be consistent `maintenance_items`.

Comment: I'm guessing the main problem is modeling though you should most likely be doing an inderect relationship: `Event has_many :equipment, has_many :maintenance_items, though:  :equipment` instead of duplicating it. You also seem confused about how rails handles arrays of nested records in params - it enumerates them from 0. The index is not based on the id.

Comment: I can understand the perceived confusion, given the data model.  I understand rails enumerates builds of nested items from 0.  But what I am after is fields_for recode that are already created; thus they have to reference the child record id, not the array enumeration.